# Is there a general rule for tracking an error?

Tags: linux, troubleshooting

I would like to start with an example here just to make it easy
to convey my question.

I have uncommented the following line from the /etc/pam.d/su file

```
auth   required   pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

thus making it mandatory for a user to be a member of the wheel group
to run the `su` command. Then I have tried the following :

```
[ssam@centos ~]$ su
Password: 
su: incorrect password
```

Here the user `ssam` is **not** a member of the wheel group so the access
is denied, the way things should go! But I had a feeling that the error message
shown here is a bit inappropriate, because I have indeed entered the right password for the root. For some user who is genuine, it would take a while
to figure out what actual problem is(hopefully).

In cases as shown above and in general, what should be the first step to start with when troubleshooting a Linux system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Double checking the configuration

  This is the first thing you want to make sure is correct. It is also the one most likely responsible for any errors. Yes, there are bugs in any software, but things like `su` are so used so much, that it is much more likely that you have misconfigured your system, than that there is a bug in the code.
- checking system logs (goes actually hand in hand with the previous step)
- running the application in question in verbose mode
- `strace`, `ltrace`
- `gdb`, source code

The error messages are often misleading for several reasons. One is they often merge different paths through the code. Second, especially for security-sensitive applications like `su`, `sudo` or `ssh` do it to give less cues to an attacker. In this particular case however, I believe the PAM architecture us to blame - `su` calls a function which returns error code which means authentication failed. From historical reasons, this is believed to be a password mismatch  (please note that I'm writing this without looking at the actual code, so feel free to convince me otherwise).

Comment: some would consider this to be a bug in su. it shouldn't say "incorrect password".  it should say "no, go away. don't ask why. i could tell you but then i'd have to kill you".

Comment: Sure, but where would be all that fun of users desperately trying to `su` when they are not allowed to do that? :)

Comment: @peterph: `by double checking the configuration`, is the implied idea related to the layered security in linux?
if so, could you expand it a bit more?

Comment: @sjsam, please see updated answer.